# Why I cannot access a property in an array of objects if not in a loop?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm working with Vue 3.
If I write this:

```
<p v-for="(prs, index) in settings.pressure">{{settings.pressure[0].value}}</p>
```

I see the value correctly, while if I use this (the one I need):

```
<p>{{settings.pressure[0].value}}</p>
```

it throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

How could it be defined in the first version and undefined in the second?

Comment: I don't know vue.js, but the `for` loop is waiting for `settings.pressure` to be defined. Without the loop, you're trying to access the variable before it's defined.

Comment: if `settings.pressure` is undefined, then you will get that error how is `settings.pressure` declared?

Comment: Can you also share the code on how you initialize the `settings` and add the data for `pressure`?

Answer (score 2):

Given the expression `settings.pressure[0].value`,

- placing it outside of `v-for` and looking at the received error tells us that, at some point after mounting, `settings.pressure` is `undefined`. And `undefined` does not have a `0` property. It doesn't have *any* property and trying to access a property on it will produce the error you're seeing
- placing it inside the `v-for` and not seeing an error tells us that, at some point after mounting, `settings.pressure` is assigned an iterable collection ***<sup>1</sup>***, at which point the `v-for` template is executed once for each item in the collection. Because this happens after `settings.value` has been populated the expression no longer errors.

A likely scenario is that `settings.pressure` is `undefined` when the component is mounted and gets populated shortly after by some data received from a pending request.

Important **side-note**: if `settings.pressure[0]`, when populated, is a [ref()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html), you don't need (nor want) to use `.value` in `<template />`. All refs are unwrapped by Vue automatically in template (should be used without `.value`). This doesn't apply if `settings.pressure[0]` is an object with a `value` property, of course.

---

The main take-away here is that the `v-for` template code is not necessarily run when the component is mounted, unless its value is iterable. It is run when the iterable collection governing the `v-for` gets populated, once for each item in the collection.

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - `v-for` can iterate over arrays, js maps, sets, objects or a positive number (Vue internally turns `n` into an `Array.from({ length: n })`).

Comment: OP says that in the first example that they can “_see the value correctly_”, doesn’t that imply the loop does run and accesses the value? Also the error that OP posted suggests that the issue is with pressure being undefined, rather than an empty array?

Comment: The loop runs when `settings.pressure` gets populated. Once for each item in `settings.pressure`. But it gets populated after the component is mounted. We know this because the code errors outside of the `v-for`. If `settings.pressure` were populated on mount, the code would not error outside of `v-for`.

Comment: @NickPersons, it is a very common scenario when iterating over a collection of items returned by a remote API. While the request is pending the collection is empty. When the data is fetched and assigned, the `v-for` renders them.

Comment: Oh yep, completely forgot that the loop will run when pressure gets populated. Makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that settings.pressure is undefined when the template is loaded.

You are able to `for in loop` an undefined element without throwing an error. Since it does not loop over anything, `<p>{{settings.pressure?.[0].value}}</p>` will not be evaluated. As such it gives time for your settings.pressure state to be loaded which will render the element as expected.

The code below will print "No error thrown"

```
try {
    for (let i in undefined) {}
    console.log("No error thrown")
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error thrown")
}
```

Your second answer however, immediately access's the first element of the array which is undefined. This will throw the error you have.

You may want to try using an optional so that an error is not thrown until the state is loaded.

`<p>{{settings.pressure?.[0].value}}</p>`